# Is this correct: "Should you have something that I can do, please feel free to assign me task."

Tags: email

I want to send an Email to my professor, and say "Should you have something that I can do, please feel free to assign me task."

I assume that "Should you" = "If you", is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Should you* does serve the same purpose as *if you*, but the use of *should* as a conditional clause is unnecessarily formal in most cases. It's technically correct, but a seasoned English speaker would overwhelmingly favor *if* in this situation.

Also, "assign me task" is entirely awkward and incorrect. You can either rework it to say *assign the task to me* or use a more casual *let me know*.

Comment: The problem with "to assign me task" is that "task" is both countable and a subsequent reference to an established referent (something that I can do).  We want the definite article here: "to assign me the task".

Comment: They're both valid solutions, but the phrase structure of "to assign me the task" still seems flowery and stilted. Less formal language would suffice and convey a more casual familiarity with English.